# Finding the sample mean of replicated data in R

Tags: r

so I just started programming in R and am still pretty unfamiliar with the software.

Recently, I was tasked with finding the means (separately) of a replicated group of data, where my main function is a simple continuous uniform distribution.

After generating 500 replications of the distribution using `runif(5, min = 15, max = 30)`, this table was created.

[image: 500 data replications]

What I'm currently looking for to find the sample mean for each version (V1, V2, etc.) separately, and have it paste out like this, but with 500 different means.

[image]

Is there a method to generate the data table first (as I already did), before finding the sample mean later? I tried using `meanreplicate5 <- replicate(500, mean(replicate5))`, seeing "replicate5" was already defined with the data table, but it just gave me 500 values of the same number, 22.5.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: `apply(replicate5, 1, mean)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Column mean of data.frame (list) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467904/column-mean-of-data-frame-list-in-r). See for example the second answer using [`colMeans`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25469584/10782538)

Comment: Using `replicate(500, mean(runif(5, min = 15, max = 30)))` would've also given expected output (much slower than generating the mtrix and using `colMeans`)

Comment: @AllanCameron brilliant, apply(replicate5, 2, mean) got me the result I wanted. Thanks for showing me the apply function!

Comment: @Oliver, Ahh, I see, I'll give your function a try! My lecturer did mention something like that, but I was just wondering if it was possible to generate and calculate separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was given by @Allan Cameron using the apply function: `apply(replicate5, 2, mean)`.